# Fancybox: The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

This particular topic has some answers on SO, but none of them solves my problem. I have no idea where to look here, although I suspect it's something very simple.

- When I try to open a url in a Fancybox **manually** (i.e. by 'physically' clicking a link) it works.
- If I however try to open it on page load **automatically** (i.e. by faking clicking a link), it doesn't work at all and gives me the error I mention in my title.

The HTML is simple:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.nl/url/to/whatever" class="fancybox hidden_link">test</a>
```

The Javascript I'm using to automatically click it, is pretty straightforward too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
    $(".hidden_link").fancybox().trigger("click");
});
```

The event goes off (a Fancybox opens), but it shows nothing more than the 'content cannot be loaded' message.
I see my own page in the Fancybox when I click the link manually.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Following the error message's advice, I tried later, but even that didn't help.

Comment: I may just be ignorant here, but why the `.fancybox()` call on the link if you're trying to mimic the effect of manually clicking the link? Can't you just use `.click()` directly on the object returned by the jQuery selector?

Comment: I thought that, but removing it stops the Fancybox from opening at all.

Comment: Have you checked out the examples [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions)? In particular point 12 (Launch fancyBox on page load) has [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Py2RA/) that seems related to what you're doing while being slightly different from the code you've posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having this link :

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.nl/url/to/whatever" class="fancybox hidden_link">test</a>
```

... this script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        width : 380, // or whatever
        height: 280
    }).trigger("click");
});​
```

... should do the job for both, manually and programmatically.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7dFYQ/1/)**

**Notice** that I used `type: "iframe"` since the content is an external page. The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) should be considered in any case.

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the facets of same-origin policy. The exact behavior differs from browser to browser. See http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Navigation_and_content_inclusion_across_domains

Here's the [summary per browser version](http://screencast.com/t/E2gXXuJ3b7s).

There's clearly a security concern here, because clicking links with JavaScript can cause actions on your behalf. That may be destructive on sites where GET requests cause state change, because a header (like a cookie) authenticating you will be sent with that GET request as well.

Comment: I doubt that. It doesn't work in any browser. And besides, fireing the click event works, but something doesn't get through to Fancybox.

Comment: I can't help thinking the clicking isn't the problem, because it **does** click. I **do** get the Fancybox onload, but it just doesn't show my page...

Comment: Yes, I get it. My guess is that the browser is smart enough to figure out that an HTTP request was effectively triggered by JavaScript, and therefore it gets blocked.

Comment: The problem occurs in all browsers, probably including the browsers the other people tested with when given this solution... I think I should keep looking for now. There's no real alternative for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is something like same origin policy.

You get from google response: [X-Frame-Options  SAMEORIGIN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

If you link to subpage within your domain it should work.

Comment: Sorry, Google was just an example. I'm linking to something in my own domain.

Comment: thats strange, because it's working perfectly for me. what firebug shows you?

Comment: Nothing. I just copied that line to my project. Do you have any response in console from that GET request?

Comment: I only see my POST request (I fire this click event after a POST / button click), I can't find the request to my 'http://www.mydomain.nl/url/to/whatever'. I do see a GET request if I click it manually (which is working)...

Comment: so there is more than only triggering click. you should show full code then. Check trigger is working ok when page is loaded (without POST pasrt) and if it's ok, then problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I gave the author a while.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        content: $("#popup"),
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers   : {
            overlay : {
                closeClick: false,
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/YkH5G/1/

By author plugin: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/410

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this is applicable in my situation. Could you elaborate?

Comment: The author says: That is not how the script works. Either you create a link to manually open or hidden form.